# How to show one array in another array in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I have table of a survey,answer and user. Answer and survey table is linked by user_id also user and survey is linked with user_id.

I want to show answers and user and comment for a survey. comment is inside survey table.

I want to get the result in this format:

```
   { 
    result:1,
    message:'success',
    survey:[ 
    {
        answers:
        [

        ],
        user:
        {

        }
        comment:
    },
    {
        answers:
        [

        ],
        user:
        {

        }
        comment:
    }   
    ]  
}
```

getAllSurveyByDoctor function:

```
    function getAllSurveyByDoctor($user_id)
    {
        $database = new SurveyDatabase(SurveyConstants::DBHOST,SurveyConstants::DBUSER,SurveyConstants::DBPASS,SurveyConstants::DBNAME);
        $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from survey where `user_id` = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
        $survey = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $surveys = array();
        $answers = array();

        if (count($survey) > 0) {

            foreach($survey as $row)
            {

                $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT answer.answer_id, answer.survey_id, answer.question_id, answer.rating, answer.user_id, question.question_id, question.question, question.type FROM `answer` INNER JOIN `question` ON
 answer.question_id = question.question_id WHERE answer.user_id = ? and answer.survey_id = ?");

                $s_id = $row['survey_id'];

                $stmt->execute(array($user_id,$s_id));
                $answer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT users.user_id,users.email_id,users.pass,users.address,users.name,survey.survey_id,survey.user_id FROM `users` INNER JOIN `survey` ON users.user_id = survey.user_id WHERE users.user_id = ?");

                $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
                $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $comment = $row['comment'];

             //   $surveys[] = $row;
                $answers = $answer;
                $surveys[] = $answers;
                $surveys[] = $user;
                $surveys[] = $comment;
            }

            $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success", "surveys" => $surveys);
            return json_encode($response);
        }

        else {
            $response = array("status"=>-1,"message"=>"surveys list is empty");
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```

I get the result like this:

```
    {
  "status": 1,
  "message": "Success",
  "surveys": [
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "50",
        "survey_id": "35",
        "question_id": "1",
        "rating": "4",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Scheduling appointments",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "51",
        "survey_id": "35",
        "question_id": "2",
        "rating": "6",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Office environment",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "0",
    [],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "0",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "54",
        "survey_id": "37",
        "question_id": "1",
        "rating": "4",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Scheduling appointments",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "55",
        "survey_id": "37",
        "question_id": "2",
        "rating": "6",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Office environment",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "0",
    [],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "csdcs",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "72",
        "survey_id": "49",
        "question_id": "7",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor listens and answers questions",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "73",
        "survey_id": "49",
        "question_id": "6",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor explains medical condition(s)",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "74",
        "survey_id": "50",
        "question_id": "8",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor spends enough time with patients",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "75",
        "survey_id": "50",
        "question_id": "3",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Staff helpfulness",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "76",
        "survey_id": "51",
        "question_id": "7",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor listens and answers questions",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "77",
        "survey_id": "51",
        "question_id": "6",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor explains medical condition(s)",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "78",
        "survey_id": "52",
        "question_id": "8",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor spends enough time with patients",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "79",
        "survey_id": "52",
        "question_id": "5",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Trust in doctor's decision",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "80",
        "survey_id": "53",
        "question_id": "1",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Scheduling appointments",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "81",
        "survey_id": "53",
        "question_id": "7",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor listens and answers questions",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    "",
    [
      {
        "answer_id": "82",
        "survey_id": "54",
        "question_id": "6",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Doctor explains medical condition(s)",
        "type": "rating"
      },
      {
        "answer_id": "83",
        "survey_id": "54",
        "question_id": "3",
        "rating": "5",
        "user_id": "9",
        "question": "Staff helpfulness",
        "type": "rating"
      }
    ],
    {
      "user_id": "9",
      "email_id": "user7@gmail.com",
      "pass": "user7",
      "address": "miraroad",
      "name": "user7",
      "survey_id": "35"
    },
    ""
  ]
}
```

I am getting some what format same as I want. I am getting answers array, user and comment after that. But how I can name it? Can not identify from this result that where are answers, user and comment. I want to name it. How can I? Thank you.

Comment: $surveys[] = is just sequentially adding a new value to the array. If you want to name it. Use a key counter. Like $surveys[$i]['user_id'] = $user, $surveys[$i]['comment'] = $comment. Make sure to increase the counter.

Comment: Alexis' solution works as well. A way to do it without the need of a counter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create an associative array for each survey. Inside this associative array, assign your keys and your values. Here's how it looks :

```
function getAllSurveyByDoctor($user_id)
    {
        $database = new SurveyDatabase(SurveyConstants::DBHOST,SurveyConstants::DBUSER,SurveyConstants::DBPASS,SurveyConstants::DBNAME);
        $dbConnection = $database->getDB();

        $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT * from survey where `user_id` = ?");
        $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
        $survey = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $surveys = array();
        $answers = array();

        if (count($survey) > 0) {

            foreach($survey as $row)
            {

                $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT answer.answer_id, answer.survey_id, answer.question_id, answer.rating, answer.user_id, question.question_id, question.question, question.type FROM `answer` INNER JOIN `question` ON
 answer.question_id = question.question_id WHERE answer.user_id = ? and answer.survey_id = ?");

                $s_id = $row['survey_id'];

                $stmt->execute(array($user_id,$s_id));
                $answer = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare("SELECT users.user_id,users.email_id,users.pass,users.address,users.name,survey.survey_id,survey.user_id FROM `users` INNER JOIN `survey` ON users.user_id = survey.user_id WHERE users.user_id = ?");

                $stmt->execute(array($user_id));
                $user = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                $comment = $row['comment'];

             //   $surveys[] = $row;

                //We create the "survey" associative array
                $survey = [];
                $answers = $answer;
                $survey['answers']= $answers;
                $survey['user'] = $user;
                $survey['comment']=$comment;
                //We add the survey array to the survey
                $surveys[] = $survey;
            }

            $response = array("status" => 1, "message" => "Success", "surveys" => $surveys);
            return json_encode($response);
        }

        else {
            $response = array("status"=>-1,"message"=>"surveys list is empty");
            return json_encode($response);
        }
    }
```